# Recursively Rename Files and Directories with Bash on macOS

Tags: bash, macos, find, rename

I'm writing a script that will perform some actions, and one of those actions is to find all occurrences of a string in both file names and directory names, and replace it with another string.

I have this so far

```sh
find . -name "*foo*" -type f -depth | while read file; do
    newpath=${file//foo/bar}
    mv "$file" "$newpath"
done
```

This works fine as long as the path to the file doesn't also contain `foo`, but that isn't guaranteed.

I feel like the way to approach this is to ONLY change the file names first, then go back through and change the directory names, but even then, if you have a structure that has more than one directory with `foo` in it, it will not work properly.

Is there a way to do this with built in macOS tools? (I say built-in, because this script is going to be distributed to some other folks in our organization and it can't rely on any packages to be installed).

Comment: You could separate the Pathname from the Filename and then do your substitution and then rebuild/join them together before you do the renaming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separating the path_name from the file_name, something like.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while read -r file; do
  path_name="${file%/*}"; printf 'Path is %s\n' "$path_name"
  file_name="${file#"$path_name"}"; printf 'Filename is %s\n' "$file_name"
  newpath="$path_name${file_name//foo/bar}"
  echo mv -v "$file" "$newpath"
done < <(find . -name "*foo*" -type f)
```

Have a look at `basename` and `dirname` as well.

The `printf`'s is just there to show which is the path and the filename.

The script just replace `foo` to `bar` from the file_name, It can be done with the path_name as well, just use the same syntax.

```
newpath="${path_name//bar/more}${file_name//foo/bar}"
```

So renaming both path_name and file_name.

Or renaming the path_name and then the file_name like your idea is an option also.

```
path_name="${file%/*}"
file_name="${file#"$path_name"}"
new_pathname="${path_name//bar/more}"

mv -v "$path_name" "$new_pathname"

new_filename="${file_name//foo/bar}"

mv -v "${new_pathname%/*}$file_name" "$new_pathname$new_filename"
```

There are no additional external tool/utility used, except from the ones being used by your script.

Remove the `echo` If you're satisfied with the result/output.

Comment: I'll give it a shot.

Comment: This works for the file names, but can't change the directory paths at the same time as the file name since the directory doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes, the directory need to exists before it can be renamed.

Comment: I ended up going with something very similar to what you have here and it worked. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-execdir` to run a command on just the filename (basename) in the relevant directory:

```
find . -depth -name '*foo*' -execdir bash -c 'mv -- "${1}" "${1//foo/bar}"' _ {} \;
```